# How to auto refresh the page without left the last place of user

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem. I am making a Blog Page in which Users can upload Blogs.

**What i am trying to do**

I want Blog page to auto refresh the Page. without auto going at the Top of the Page.
I want user to stay still on that place where user was before refresh.

**What have i tried**

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog_posts';

    }, 5000); //refresh/redirect after 5 seconds.
</script>
```

Work of this Code :- This `JavaScript` code refresh the page in every 5 Seconds

*What's the problem in this `JavaScript Code`* ^

In the JavaScript code below. It is working fine, It refresh the page very well in every 5 seconds. BUT when it refresh the page then if i am scrolling down while seeing blogposts then Page Refresh, then after refresh i find myself on top of the page. ( If a user is scrolling down and JavaScript refresh the page then the user find himself/herself on top the page ). That's Why its a Big Problem.

I don't know very much of `JavaScript`.I don't know what to do.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Answer of this Question.

Solution:-

```
<script>

    window.addEventListener('load',function() {
        if(localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition') !== null)
           window.scrollTo(0, 
localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition'));
},false);

</script>
```

I put this right below the Refreshing Code of `JavaScript`. It store the last position then get back to the position when the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ajax and propper.js to achieve your goal.